# Kotlin bytecode buildable with Java

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to produce the same bytecode that the Kotlin JVM compiler produces using pure Java source files? If it makes a difference depending on the platform, I'm asking for the major desktop operating systems, not Android.

Comment: How strictly the "same" are we talking here? Same file hash?

Comment: In general, no. For one example, Kotlin allows characters such as spaces to be used within identifiers (using backquotes as delimiters), which Java doesn't. And for another, Kotlin generates various metadata (such as parameter names and default values) that Java can't.